# Collecting chat messages for YouTube public live videos

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use YouTube apis to collect chat messages from public live videos. I am able to get regular comments but unable to get live comments. Let me know if there is an api for this.

I have tried LiveStreams: list (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list#try-it); however, it requires liveChatId which I could not get for a YouTube live video.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Can you share your authorisation code for me. i am stuck with that.please

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [reference page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages) from the Live Streaming API.

Comment: The list api requires liveChatId. How can you get liveChatId for a youTube live video? Here is an example youTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nk7IngWdcI4

Comment: Try following the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683878/youtube-api-how-do-i-get-the-livechatid

Comment: @Vivek did that answer your question?

Comment: Is there an equivalent API to retrieve the same chat after the livestream has completed and archived?  As stated in the referenced page: “after the event ends, live chat is no longer available for that event.”. But I know there’s a Python solution (chat-replay-downloader) that does this for completed livestreams.  That won’t work with private videos since it doesn’t allow sign-in.  I would like to retrieve my own channel’s livestream chats after-the-fact if possible, even if they’ve been marked Private.